# Import module that depends on module with same name

Tags: python, django

My project is based on django and in one app I want to import another module. I installed the module with pip and I'm importing it:

```
from django.conf import settings
from problematic_package.app.templatetags import test
```

The issue is that `problematic_package` is also django based and in test.py they have:

```
from django.conf import settings
...
```

Here python will think settings is actually the object from my django project, instead of the imported one.

I can't change the project installed with pip. What other solutions do I have?

Comment: In Django there is always exactly one `django.conf.settings`. It _should_ use the same one as your code.

Comment: " object from my django project, instead of the imported one." well no, technically you are both importing the settings from Django, does the package require specific settings that your project conflicts with? How does it expect `conf.settings` to be initialized?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich ok, but it doesn't make sense in my case, since this module is third party and it has its own settings and other django files

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen the package requires settings, it doesn't conflict with mine I think. it's just that it doesn't find the specific variables in settings that it needs.

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga if it is expecting a particular variable then where is it expecting to get the variable from? if it has it's own config settings file you might be able to get away with `from THEIR_SETTINGS import *` in your configs module.

Comment: What about `from django.conf import settings as my_settings` then you have to adjust all settings relations with my_settings in that file.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen good idea, works, but I have to change a few things, not the cleanest